# how to determine at runtime which function to call in vbscript

Tags: vbscript, qtp

The range of input values possible is quite huge in my case. So a select-case methodology will not work. 
So based on my input say flowers.. doffodil,lily,rose,etc, my function name to call would be `flowerdoffodil()`, `flowerlily()`, `flowerrose()`, etc. Ech of these functions are already defined. 
Only which one to call will need to be determined at runtime based on my input.
Is there a way to do this in vb script? 
Note: I am a rookie programmer and am using QTP for automation.

Answer (score 5):

Use [GetRef()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekabbe10%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) as in:

```
Option Explicit

Function flowerdoffodil()
  flowerdoffodil = "my name is daffodil!"
End Function

Function flowerlily()
  flowerlily = "my name is lily!"
End Function

Function flowerrose()
  flowerrose = "my name is rose!"
End Function

Dim aInp : aInp = Split("doffodil lily rose")
Dim sFnc
For Each sFnc In aInp
    Dim fncX : Set fncX = GetRef("flower" & sFnc)
    Dim sRes : sRes = fncX()
    WScript.Echo sFnc, TypeName(fncX), sRes
Next
```

output:

```
cscript 30161364.vbs
doffodil Object my name is daffodil!
lily Object my name is lily!
rose Object my name is rose!
```

Further food for thought: You can use a Dictionary:

```
Dim dicFncs : Set dicFncs = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set dicFncs("doffodil") = GetRef("flowerdoffodil")
Set dicFncs("lily") = GetRef("flowerlily")
Set dicFncs("rose") = GetRef("flowerrose")
```

and call the function(s) like:

```
Dim sRes : sRes = dicFncs(sFnc)()
```

(See also: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13127606/603855), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7645444/603855), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16715006/603855))

Comment: Alternative would be using Eval & Co., which would avoid using GetRef (not sure if this is better, but it might be easier to understand the concept of "evaluate this string" than the concept of function pointers/delegates).